# get the request values in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder, laravel-request, laravel-response

I wish to make search query by datepicker and select field.
How could I get the requests values from below view file to controller?
Where could I modify in the code? thanks.

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form', 'method' => 'get', 'url' => url('/pdfs/job_finished_search'))) !!} 
       {!! Form::input('text', 'datepicker_from', null, ['placeholder' => 'Fra', 'id' => 'datepicker_from']) !!}
       {!! Form::input('text', 'datepicker_to', null, ['placeholder' => 'Til', 'id' => 'datepicker_to']) !!} 
       {!! Form::select('customer_name', $jobs->pluck('customer_name', 'customer_name')->all(), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
       {!! Form::submit('Søke', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm']) !!} 
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function job_finished_search(Request $request, Job $jobs)
{

    $jobs = Job::onlyTrashed()
            ->whereBetween('created_at', array(
              (Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_from'))->startOfDay()),
              (Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_to'))->endOfDay())))
            ->where('customer_name', 'like', '%'.$request->customer_name.'%')
            ->orderBy('deleted_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(15);

       if (empty($jobs)){
           Flash::error('Search result not found');
    }

    return view('pdfs.index', ['jobs' => $jobs]); 
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your post showing what returns a `dd($request->all());` in your controller?

Comment: @Asur, hi dd result was, array:3 [▼
  "datepicker_from" => "10/01/2017"
  "datepicker_to" => "10/31/2017"
  "customer_name" => "asdfasdf"
]

Comment: @Asur, I think the core is how to adjust 2 parameters to return view.

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple way to get the request data e.g to get datepicker_from value you can use any of the below

```
$request->datepicker_from 
$request->input('datepicker_from')
$request->get('datepicker_from')
```

choose the one you like the most

refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests

Answer (score 3):

To get request values you can use the `get` method, try:

`$customer = $request->get('customer_name','default_value');`

Answer (score 0):

To get request values, you can set an object like `$input= $request->all()`. Then you can make use of the object which is an array to get at specific fields, e.g to access your date picker, you can write `$input['datepicker_from']`. You need to place `$input= $request->all()` before you declare the `$jobs` object in your code.

Comment: `$input= $request->all()` returns an array, not an object. The explained method is good to know for people but you would better fixing your wording to be precise.